# not getting the proper solution for number base checker

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, logic

The user enters the base from 2- 10.
The user then enters a number they would like to convert to in base ten. 
But first the program checks if the number is in the base they entered.

CODE:

```
//ERROR CHECKING FOR DIGITS/ GETTING PROPER DIGITS INPUT
int digit = 0;
bool checker;
cout << "enter number for conversion: "; //Prompt user for base data
cin >> num;

if (num < base){
    checker = true;
}
else{
    checker = false;

}

//insert each number of digitN inside the array & check if each value is part of the base
while (checker == false){
    int len = (std::to_string(num)).size(); //attain array size
    for (int i = 0; i <= (len - 1); i++)
    {
        digit = num % 10;
        if (digit >= base)
        {
            checker = false;
            i = len;
        }
        else
        {
            checker = true;
        }
        num = (num / 10);

    }
    cout << "enter PROPER number for conversion: "; //Prompt user for base data
    cin >> num;

}
```

I appear to be getting an error in the for loop. Can someone help me with the logic.
Once the program accepts a number, it checks every digit of that number to see if it is in the base. If so, checker will be true otherwise false.

Comment: Just download a debugger e.g. Visual Studio Express for Windows, run your program in there, and the error should be very easy to find.  You can single step, running it one line at a time, while watching the variables.

Comment: Your use of `checker` seems counter intuitive. Shouldn't it be

`if (num < base){
    checker = false; 
}
else {
    checker = true;
}`

and

`while (checker == true )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple to make the checker.

```
bool is_valid;
unsigned int digit;
unsigned int x = ( num >= 0 ? num : -num );

do
{
    digit = x % 10;
} while ( ( is_valid = digit < base ) && ( x /= 10 ) );
```

Instead of the ternary operator you could use standard function `abs`

Instead of variable name checker I use name is_valid. It is not importnat what name you will use.